# Setting a validator on a QLineEdit object PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

So I'm struggling to find a solution that will point me in the right direction to set a validator on a QLineEdit to only accept floats within a defined range. I've seen some examples out there but I think I'm getting tripped up on the syntax. Still very new to this so not very knowledgeable and not quite sure what I'm doing yet.

So I have a program I'm working on where the GUI elements has been created with Qt Designer, and I've been using Python to create all the moving parts interacting /calling the ui elements from the compiled main.ui file after it's been converted to Python. So far, I've been calling these objects using ui.(the object name).(some function/signal).

So let's say I want to set a validator for one of these QLineEdit objects that I've named "lineEditSHStart". Usually ui.lineEditSHStart.(some function) has worked for me, but I'm not having any luck with getting a validator to work with this way.

How would you go about doing this? From the examples I've seen so far, this has been done through creating the elements from scratch in Python so the syntax of "self.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(9999.00, -9999.00, 2))" has been used. I haven't seen anything working with the situation I have so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Snip from the compiled file

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1517, 905)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 905))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(2000, 905))
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 1001, 431))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.groupBoxBT = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBoxBT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 271, 341))
        self.groupBoxBT.setObjectName("groupBoxBT")
        self.comboBoxBT1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT1.setCurrentText("")
        self.comboBoxBT1.setObjectName("comboBoxBT1")
        self.comboBoxBT2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT2.setObjectName("comboBoxBT2")
        self.comboBoxBT3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT3.setObjectName("comboBoxBT3")
        self.comboBoxBT4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT4.setObjectName("comboBoxBT4")
        self.comboBoxBT5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 220, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT5.setObjectName("comboBoxBT5")
        self.comboBoxBT6 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT6.setObjectName("comboBoxBT6")
        self.labelBTType = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.labelBTType.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 47, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.labelBTType.setFont(font)
        self.labelBTType.setObjectName("labelBTType")
        self.comboBoxBT7 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.comboBoxBT7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 121, 22))
        self.comboBoxBT7.setObjectName("comboBoxBT7")
        self.lineEditBT1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 60, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.lineEditBT1.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT1.setText("")
        self.lineEditBT1.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.lineEditBT1.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT1.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT1.setObjectName("lineEditBT1")
        self.lineEditBT2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 100, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT2.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT2.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT2.setObjectName("lineEditBT2")
        self.lineEditBT3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 140, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT3.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT3.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT3.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT3.setObjectName("lineEditBT3")
        self.lineEditBT4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 180, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT4.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT4.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT4.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT4.setObjectName("lineEditBT4")
        self.lineEditBT5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 220, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT5.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT5.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT5.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT5.setObjectName("lineEditBT5")
        self.lineEditBT6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 260, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT6.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT6.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT6.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT6.setObjectName("lineEditBT6")
        self.lineEditBT7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.lineEditBT7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 300, 51, 20))
        self.lineEditBT7.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEditBT7.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEditBT7.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEditBT7.setObjectName("lineEditBT7")
        self.labelBTQuanity = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBoxBT)
        self.labelBTQuanity.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 81, 21))
```

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
import gui_main
import numpy as np 



#==========================================
# create app and main window + dialog GUI
# =========================================

app = QApplication(sys.argv)



window = QWidget()
ui = gui_main.Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(window)


#========================================
# GUI event handler and related functions
# =======================================

def calcTotalDynamicHead():        # Define function to compute all calculations based off user input variables when "calculate" button is pressed
    
    # Creating a dictionary of key/value pairs from the items chosen from the combo boxes and their corresponding quanities 
    btList = {ui.comboBoxBT1.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT1.text(), ui.comboBoxBT2.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT2.text(), ui.comboBoxBT3.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT3.text(), ui.comboBoxBT4.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT4.text(), ui.comboBoxBT5.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT5.text(), ui.comboBoxBT6.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT6.text(), ui.comboBoxBT7.currentText() : ui.lineEditBT7.text()}
    
    # Creating a dictionary of variable pairs of item types and their straight length conversion factors
    conversionBT = {'Standard Tee':'5.7133', 'Through Tee': '1.7893', 'Standard Elbow': '2.6701', 'Medium Sweep Elbow': '2.258', 'Long Sweep Elbow': '1.7893', '45 Degree Bend': '1.2308'}
    
    # Creating a dictionary of variable pairs from the items chosen from the combo boxes and their corresponding quanities
    valveList = {ui.comboBoxV1.currentText() : ui.lineEditV1.text(), ui.comboBoxV2.currentText() : ui.lineEditV2.text(), ui.comboBoxV3.currentText() : ui.lineEditV3.text(), ui.comboBoxV4.currentText() : ui.lineEditV4.text(), ui.comboBoxV5.currentText() : ui.lineEditV5.text(), ui.comboBoxV6.currentText() : ui.lineEditV6.text(), ui.comboBoxV7.currentText() : ui.lineEditV7.text() }
    
    # Creating a dictionary of variable pairs of item types and their straight length conversion factors
    conversionValve = {'Globe Valve' : '28.716', 'Swing Check Valve' : '6.7493', 'Gate Valve Open' : '0.5668', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed' : '71.126', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed' : '16.971', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed' : '3.3958', 'Plug Valve': '7.179'}
    
    # Grabbing all necessary variables from ui elements for calculations and error handling
    totalStraightPipe = ui.lineEditPipeLen.text()
    pipeDia = ui.lineEditDia.text()
    startEle = ui.lineEditSHStart.text()
    endEle = ui.lineEditSHEnd.text()
    highPt = ui.lineEditSHHigh.text()
    targetFlow = ui.lineEditFHTarget.text()
    minFlow = ui.lineEditFHMin.text()
    maxFlow = ui.lineEditFHMax.text()
    kVal = ui.lineEditFHKvalue.text()
    cFactor = ui.lineEditFHCfac.text()
    minVel = ui.spinBoxFHVelMin.value()  
    maxVel = ui.spinBoxFHVelMax.value() 
    
    # Creating empty lists and dictionaries for storing calculated values
    btCalcs = []
    valveCalcs = []
    calcFlows = {}
    

    try: 
        # Loop through the Bends and Tees combo boxes and look for selections in order to convert items to their straight length equivalents 
        for item in btList:
            
            if item != '' :
                
                quanity = btList[item]
                
                eqLenPerFit = float(conversionBT[item]) * int(pipeDia)
        
                totalEqLen = float(eqLenPerFit) * float(quanity)
                
                btCalcs.append(totalEqLen)
              
            else:
                
                pass
        
        # Loop through the Valve combo boxes and look for selections in order to covert items to their straight length equivalents
        for item in valveList:
            
            if item != '':
                
                quanity = valveList[item]
                
                eqLenPerValve = float(conversionValve[item]) * int(pipeDia)
                
                totalEqLen = float(eqLenPerValve) * float(quanity)
                
                valveCalcs.append(totalEqLen)
                
            else:
                
                pass
            
        # Sum all the converted straight length values appended to the Bends and Tees list
        totalBt = sum(map(float,btCalcs))
        
        # Sum all the converted straight length values appened to the Valves list
        totalValves = sum(map(float, valveCalcs))
        
        # Calculate the total equivalnet length for all Bends and Tees, Valves, and Straight Pipe Segment
        totalEqLength = totalBt + totalValves + float(totalStraightPipe)
        
        # Calculate the Static Head 
        if endEle < highPt:
            staticHead = float(highPt) - float(startEle)
        else:
            staticHead = float(endEle) - float(startEle)
        
        # Create a list of defined flow rates from the user input Min and Max Flows in order to perform calculations for each flow rate
        flowList = np.arange(int(minFlow),int(maxFlow)+1, 100)
        
        # Loop through the defined flow ranges and calculate the Head Loss per 100ft, Velocity, Velocity Head, Friction Head, and Total Dynamic Head for each flow rate
        for flow in flowList:
           
            # Create an empty dictionary with each flow rate as a key and an empty list for storing corresponding calculated values. Plan on expanding in the future and will be nice to have all this info in a nice callable place
            calcFlows.update({flow: []})
            
            # Calculate Head Loss per 100ft
            headLoss = 2.083 * (100/int(cFactor))**1.85 * (int(flow)**1.85/int(pipeDia)**4.8655)
            
            # Calculate velocity
            velocity = (int(flow)/448.8)/(3.14159*(int(pipeDia)/24)**2)
            
            # Calculate Velocity Head
            velocityHead = int(velocity)**2 / 64.4
            
            # Calculate Friction Head
            frictionHead = int(totalEqLength) * (headLoss/1000) + (velocityHead * int(kVal))
            
            # Calculate Total Dynamic Head
            totalDynamicHead = float(staticHead) + float(frictionHead)
            
            # Append each calculation to it's corresponding flow key in the dictionary 
            calcFlows[flow].append(headLoss)
            calcFlows[flow].append(velocity)
            calcFlows[flow].append(velocityHead)
            calcFlows[flow].append(frictionHead)
            calcFlows[flow].append(totalDynamicHead)
    
        # Update all the corresponding ui elements with their calculated value
        ui.lineEditTotalEqLen.setText("{:.2f} ft".format(totalEqLength))
        ui.lineEditStaticHead.setText("{:.2f} ft".format(staticHead))
        ui.lineEditFHHeadLoss.setText("{:.2f} ft".format(calcFlows[int(targetFlow)][0]))
        ui.lineEditFHVelocity.setText("{:.2f} ft/sec".format(calcFlows[int(targetFlow)][1]))
        ui.lineEditFHVelHead.setText("{:.2f} v**2/(2g)".format(calcFlows[int(targetFlow)][2]))
        ui.lineEditFHFrictionHead.setText("{:.2f} ft".format(calcFlows[int(targetFlow)][3]))
        ui.lineEditTotalDynHead.setText("{:.2f} ft".format(calcFlows[int(targetFlow)][4]))
        
        # Checking if the calculated velocity falls within the user defined range, turns the lineEdit object green/red
        if int(minVel) < calcFlows[int(targetFlow)][1] < int(maxVel):
            ui.lineEditFHVelocity.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);")
        else:
            ui.lineEditFHVelocity.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        
        # plots all calculated total dynamic head values per flow rates into graph 
        x = flowList
        y = [calcFlows[key][-1] for key in calcFlows.keys()] 
        ui.graphWidget.plot(x,y, name = targetFlow, symbol='o', symbolSize=10)
    

    # Error handling / Checks for any empty lineEdit(s) and notifies user through a dialog box and hightlights corresponding box red 
    except:
        
        if pipeDia == '':
            ui.lineEditDia.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Pipe Diameter", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif totalStraightPipe == '':
            ui.lineEditPipeLen.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Straight Pipe Segment Length", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif startEle == '.':
            ui.lineEditSHStart.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Starting Elevation", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif endEle == '.':
            ui.lineEditSHEnd.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Ending Elevation", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif targetFlow == '':
            ui.lineEditFHTarget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Target Flow", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif minFlow == '':
            ui.lineEditFHMin.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Minimum Flow", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif maxFlow == '':
            ui.lineEditFHMax.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing Maximum Flow", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif kVal  == '':
            ui.lineEditFHKvalue.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing K Value", QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif cFactor  == '':
            ui.lineEditFHCfac.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            QMessageBox.information(window,"Information", "Missing C Factor Value", QMessageBox.Ok)
            
            
# Event handling functions for returning lineEdit object backgrounds to white after a missing value has been entered      
def resetlineEditDia():
    ui.lineEditDia.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")

def resetlineEditPipeLen():
    ui.lineEditPipeLen.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);") 

def resetlineEditSHStart():
    ui.lineEditSHStart.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    
def resetlineEditSHEnd():
    ui.lineEditSHEnd.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    
def resetlineEditFHTarget():
     ui.lineEditFHTarget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")
     
def resetlineEditFHMin():
    ui.lineEditFHMin.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    
def resetlineEditFHMax():
    ui.lineEditFHMax.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")

def resetlineEditFHKvalue():
    ui.lineEditFHKvalue.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")

def resetlineEditFHCfac():
    ui.lineEditFHCfac.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")    


#==========================================
# connect signals
#==========================================
    
# Connecting button press to calculate function
ui.calcTotalDynHeadBt.clicked.connect(calcTotalDynamicHead)

# Connecting text change signals to background resets
ui.lineEditDia.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditDia)
ui.lineEditPipeLen.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditPipeLen)
ui.lineEditSHStart.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditSHStart)
ui.lineEditSHEnd.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditSHEnd)
ui.lineEditFHTarget.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditFHTarget)
ui.lineEditFHMin.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditFHMin)
ui.lineEditFHMax.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditFHMax)
ui.lineEditFHKvalue.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditFHKvalue)
ui.lineEditFHCfac.textChanged.connect(resetlineEditFHCfac)



# Bends and Tees Combo Box Options
ui.comboBoxBT1.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])
ui.comboBoxBT2.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])
ui.comboBoxBT3.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])
ui.comboBoxBT4.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])
ui.comboBoxBT5.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])
ui.comboBoxBT6.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])
ui.comboBoxBT7.addItems(['', 'Standard Tee', 'Through Tee', 'Standard Elbow', 'Medium Sweep Elbow', 'Long Sweep Elbow', '45 Degree Bend'])

# Valves Combo Box Options
ui.comboBoxV1.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV2.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV3.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV4.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV5.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV6.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV6.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])
ui.comboBoxV7.addItems(['', 'Globe Valve', 'Swing Check Valve', 'Gate Valve Open', 'Gate Valve 3/4 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/2 Closed', 'Gate Valve 1/4 Closed', 'Plug Valve'])

# Graph styling
ui.graphWidget.setTitle("STORAGE FEED SYSTEM CURVE", color="k", size="18pt")
ui.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
ui.graphWidget.setLabel("left", "TDH (FT)", color="k", size="16pt")
ui.graphWidget.setLabel("bottom", "Flow Rate (GPM per pump)", color="k", size="16pt")
ui.graphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
ui.graphWidget.addLegend()

#=======================================
# run app
#=======================================
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've done so far?

Comment: Please edit the question, as comments do not support formatting.

Comment: Sorry about that! new to this

Comment: Is there a way to just share the .py files here? Otherwise I won't be able to post anything significant enough for you to reproduce on your end since I'm working with a ui file that was converted to a python file.

Comment: Just edit your question and paste the code you're using. Note that if you're working on the file converted by pyuic, that's *not* the correct approach, as those files should **never** be modified. To know more about using them, read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Correct, I'm not editing the file converted by pyuic. I'm just trying to figure out how to get a validator set on some of my QLineEdit objects contained within that file

Comment: Ok, let me say that your approach to implement the ui and its function is not a very good one: it's confusing, difficult to read (and maintain) and might lead to issues exactly like yours, because the object structure is obscure. I suggest you to read the link I gave my the previous comment (the answer given by max correctly shows one of the approaches explained there) and follow those guidelines. You'll find that it will make the whole code much more cleaner and clear.

Comment: I was just using a mask, but didn't like how it worked.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Still very much a newbie!

So is it considered a much better practice to not use something like Qt Designer and do everything in Python yourself? Not compiling a ui file like that?

I will read that link as well. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No, I've never said that. Using Designer or manually build the UI from code is a matter of choice, habit and requirements. Read that link and you'll understand it. On the other hand, I don't understand why you need to use a QLineEdit for float values. Can't you just use [QDoubleSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html)?

Comment: ok, good to know. And I don't have to use QLineEdit, was just what I initially picked. Again still new and learning the best way to do things. Thanks again for the info!

Comment: Consider that Qt is a very *solid* and complete framework, with more than 500 classes and thousands of functions, which provides the most common UI elements and features. Since having a field to edit numeric values is a very basic UI feature, it's unlikely that a dedicated control doesn't exist yet and requires subclassing. Since you're new to this (and, as said, there're hundreds of classes) I strongly suggest you to start by examining the whole [QtWidget classes list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) (note that not all those classes are actual widgets, but they're used by them).

Answer (score 0):

Convert ui file to python file
`python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x untitled.ui -o window.py`

**untitled.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEditSHStart"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="action_button">
     <property name="text">
      <string>PushButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

import window  # Import convert .ui file.


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = window.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        validator = QtGui.QDoubleValidator()  # Create validator.
        validator.setRange( -10.0, 9999.0, 2)
        self.ui.lineEditSHStart.setValidator(validator)  # Set validator.
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: So Max, how would one implement that when working with a PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2?

So I'm importing that file into my main.py script. Is this something that will set a validator for all QlineEdit objects?



# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):

Comment: So you are using a ui file right? and then your converting it to a python file?

Comment: Thanks Max! I'll give that a try and let you know if I can get it to work. I also updated my original post with a large example of my code from that compiled .ui file for your reference.